# PHP - How to set default value of every index of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am having trouble dealing with arrays. PHP throws an error if I access an index of an array which does not exists and It is getting difficult conditioning for every index. Is there any way I could set default value for every index of an array so even if I access a non-existent index of an array then it returns the default set value?

Comment: Define a function to access your arrays, something like this:
`function access($array, $key) { return isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key]:'Default Value'; }` and just use `access($array, 'key')` instead of `$array['key']`

Comment: This is one of those things in PHP. You need to get accustomed to checking for the presence of a key that could possibly be missing because there is no syntax to avoid it without issuing an E_NOTICE

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP default array values if key doesn't exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555758/php-default-array-values-if-key-doesnt-exist)

Comment: What is "every" index? You mean every possible index you may ever possibly want to access, which is basically infinite many indices? Or do you have only a number of defined keys? Please specify some more context.

Comment: This question was perfectly clear. Who the hell closed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do *not* want to set a default value for every index of the array, unless your array is really quite small. It would be a waste of processing and memory.

You can do this:

```
if (isset($array[$index])) {
    $var = $array[$index]; // the index exists
} else {
    $var = 'default value'; // the index does not exist
}
// now so something with $var
```

Answer (score 0):

**'Object oriented' method:**

You could create your own `ArrayAccess` implementation, which returns a default value (`null` for example) if the key you are looking for doesn't exists. The easiest way would be to extend the existing `ArrayObject` class:

```
class MyArray extends ArrayObject {
    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        if(!$this->offsetExists($offset)) {
            return null; // or some default value
        }
        return parent::offsetGet($offset);
    }
}
```

Then use this instead of `array()` :

```
$arr = new MyArray();
$arr['y'] = "I'm ok";
echo $arr['x']; // not set, default value (null) is returned.
echo $arr['y']; // prints "I'm ok"
```

**Procedural method:**

You could define a method, which safely gets a value from your arrays:

```
function safeGet($array, $key, $default = null){
    if(!is_array($array) && !$array instanceof ArrayAccess){
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$array must be an array');
    }
    return isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : $default;
}
```

Then simply access your values using this method:

```
$arr = array();
$arr['z'] = "I'm ok";

echo safeGet($arr, 'x'); // tries to access $arr['x']. prints null by default.
echo safeGet($arr, 'y', 'default'); // tries to access $arr['y']. prints 'default'.
echo safeGet($arr, 'z'); // key exists, prints "I'm ok".
```