# PHP: get array value as in Python?

Tags: php, python, arrays, get, default

In Python I can use "get" method to get value from an dictionary without error.

```
a = {1: "a", 2: "b"}
a[3] # error
a.get(3, "") # I got empty string.
```

So I search for a common/base function that do this:

```
function GetItem($Arr, $Key, $Default){
    $res = '';
    if (array_key_exists($Key, $Arr)) {
        $res = $Arr[$Key];
    } else {
        $res = $Default;
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Have same function basicly in PHP as in Python?

Thanks:
   dd

Comment: why you need a function to get the value using a key of the array. $a['key'] what is wrong with this

Comment: @zod: If the key doesn't exist, you get a PHP error. Using a function like the ones in the answers below allows you to get a default value instead of an error message.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/function.isset.php) is typically faster than `array_key_exists()`.  The parameter `$default` is initialized to an empty string if omitted.

```
function getItem($array, $key, $default = "") {
  return isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : $default;
}

// Call as
$array = array("abc" => 123, "def" => 455);
echo getItem($array, "xyz", "not here");
// "not here"
```

However, if an array key exists but has a NULL value, `isset()` won't behave the way you expect, as it will treat the `NULL` as though it doesn't exist and return `$default`.  If you expect `NULL`s in the array, you must use `array_key_exists()` instead.

```
function getItem($array, $key, $default = "") {
  return array_key_exists($key, $array) ? $array[$key] : $default;
}
```

Comment: I made another helper function which is simpler and needs fewer arguments: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25205195/1890285

Answer (score 2):

Not quite. This should behave the same.

```
function GetItem($Arr, $Key, $Default = ''){
    if (array_key_exists($Key, $Arr)) {
        $res = $Arr[$Key];
    } else {
        $res = $Default;
    }
    return $res;
}
```

The first line in your function is useless, as every code path results in `$res` being overwritten. The trick is to make the `$Default` parameter optional as above.

Keep in mind that using `array_key_exists()` can cause significant slowdowns, especially on large arrays. An alternative:

```
function GetItem($Arr, $Key, $Default = '') {
  return isset($Arr[$Key]) ? $Arr[$Key] : $Default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no base function to do that in my mind.

Your GetItem is a good way to do what you wanna do :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. or

```
function GetItem($Arr, $Key, $Default) {
  return array_key_exists($Key, $Arr)
      ? $Arr[$Key]
      : $Default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

php7 is out for a long time now so you can do

`$Arr[$Key] ?? $default`